# /RE/ vs. "RE" in awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression, syntax

In `awk`, the first argument to the `sub()` and `gsub()` functions, the second argument to the `match()` function, and the optional third argument to `split()`, is an extended regular expression.

Such an argument may be an arbitrary expression that evaluates to a string that is interpreted as a regular expression, or it may be a regular expression constant.

In `awk`, a regular expression constant is written `/RE/` for some regular expression `RE` (an "`ERE` token" in the `awk` grammar).

**Question:** Assuming that `RE` remains the same (some non-variable regular expression), are there any practical differences between using `/RE/` and using `"RE"` (a "`STRING` token" in the `awk` grammar) in a call to, e.g., `sub()`?  Alternatively: Is there any known `awk` implementation that makes a difference between these two ways of representing a regular expression in a call to the above-mentioned functions?

The reason for asking is that I recall having to modify some `awk` code that tried to use `"RE"` as a regular expression in a call to either `sub()` or `gsub()`, because, for whatever reason, the `awk` implementation at hand did the wrong thing unless I called the function with `/RE/`.

Unfortunately, this was some time ago (2+ years) so I don't remember the details and I am even uncertain what Unix I used at the time (possibly OpenBSD), but I've been meaning to ask the question ever since.

Comment: Related: https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's certainly a relevant text.

Comment: IIRC, there were several discussions around that on the austin group mailing list around that time. My vague recollection was that there was quite a bit of variations between implementations. IIRC, the POSIX position was that `$0 ~ "\f"` matches against a re that contains a formfeed character, while `$0 ~ /\f/` matches against a re that contains `\f`, but that's meant to match a form feed for the regexp engine. I don't remember what `/[\f]/` was meant to match (whether a FF or either backslash or `f`)

Comment: In any case, you need to double your backslashes inside `"..."` so it becomes a RE escaping operator (but see above about `\f`/`\b`...) and quadruple them (`$0 ~ "\\\\"`) to match a literal backslash.

Comment: With busybox awk, you can use `$0 ~ "(.)\\1"` for back references, but IIRC, that's not POSIX compliant as POSIX requires that to match the same as `$0 ~ /(.)\1/`, so any character followed by byte 0x1

Comment: See also https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1233

Comment: By the way, the optional third argument to `split()`, is a `Field Separator` which isn't quite the same as an extended regular expression. It's like a ERE plus additional functionality, e.g. when it's a singe non-blank char, even an ERE metachar, it's treated as a literal char and when it's a single blank then leading/trailing white spaces are ignored and and all other contiguous white space is treated as a single separator.

Comment: See also the `re = @/.../` and `-v re='@/.../'` misfeature of gawk

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've never had a use for it so I don't have any feelings about it either way beyond that but I'm curious - why do you say it's a misfeature? For anyone interested, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants for background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they are different in all awk implementations in the way that backslashes are used as escapes. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for this and more details:

> ... be aware that there is a
> difference between a regexp constant enclosed in slashes and a string
> constant enclosed in double quotes. If you are going to use a string
> constant, you have to understand that the string is, in essence,
> scanned twice: the first time when awk reads your program, and the
> second time when it goes to match the string on the lefthand side of
> the operator with the pattern on the right. This is true of any
> string-valued expression (such as digits_regexp, shown in the previous
> example), not just string constants.
>
> What difference does it make if the string is scanned twice? The
> answer has to do with escape sequences, and particularly with
> backslashes. To get a backslash into a regular expression inside a
> string, you have to type two backslashes.
>
> For example, `/\*/` is a regexp constant for a literal `*`. Only one
> backslash is needed. To do the same thing with a string, you have to
> type `"\\*"`. The first backslash escapes the second one so that the
> string actually contains the two characters `\` and `*`.

So, when writing a regexp the only time to consider using `"RE"` instead of `/RE/` is when:

1. The RE contains `/`s and no escapes so you can write, for example, `sub("/foo/bar","")` instead of `sub(/\/foo\/bar/,"")` just for conciseness, or
2. You NEED string delimiters for concatenation like `var=17; sub("stuff" var,"")`

otherwise always use regexp delimters (`/`) around regexps, not string delimiters (`"`).